# Wordpress WSOD + php fatal error cannot redeclare get_attached_media

Tags: php, wordpress

This might also be a wider issue with customized twentythirteen issues in 3.7.1

**Context**
A few days ago (Sun/Mon) I updated the Wordpress SEO & Google Analytics plugins, changed some meta descriptions and the site was fine, live and working. However, it's been down since Wednesday. White screen appears both for the url & the /wp-admin page

-Don't know if it updated to WP 3.7.1 automatically since I don't know what it was before..must have? because it Is currently 3.7.1
-many plugins are outdated, and are not compatible with 3.7.1. I have deactivated them

**So far I have:** erased blank lines in the functions.php as per some online recommendations and renamed the current custom theme to grant me access to the /wp-admin and the dashboard...but now im stuck

Trouble is I'm not a developer, don't know php (just basic html) and I don't quite understand the original web designer's workflow...there are 5 themes in the content folder twentyten, twentyeleven, twentythirteen, twentytwelve, twentythirteen, and custom (child?) theme called 'citystudio'

The most recent and numerous error reads:

[31-Oct-2013 08:57:33] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare get_attached_media() (previously declared in /home5/citystu3/public_html/wp-includes/media.php:1958) in /home5/citystu3/public_html/wp-content/themes/citystudio/functions.php on line 651

Line 651: is the last line of this code

```
// Get all attached media //

function get_attached_media($media_size="large", $id, $info=false) {
    $media = '<div class="cycle">'; 
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' =>     
-1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $id, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' =>  
'ASC' ); 
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                    $title = trim(strip_tags( $attachment- 
>post_title ));
                    $caption = trim(strip_tags( $attachment-
>post_excerpt ));
                    $media .= "<div class='slide'>";
                    if ($info) {
                        $media .= "<div class='content'>";
                        $media .= "<h4>".$title."</h4>";
                        if (strlen($caption)>4) $media .= "
<div class='caption'>".$caption."</div>";
                        $media .= "</div>";
                    }
                    $media .= "<img 
src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , $media_size)."' />";
                    $media .= "</div>";
                }
            }
        $media .= '</div>';
        return $media;
}
```

And this comes immediately after:

```
$tracking = get_option('citystudio_google_analytics');
if($tracking && $tracking!="") {
add_action('wp_footer', 'async_google_analytics');
function async_google_analytics() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: p.s. SORRY about the length :s

Comment: One thing I see is that `$media .= "<img` needs to be `$media .= "<img";`. Also, looks like media.php line 1958 also has a function named `get_attached_media()`, so you're going to need to refactor one of them.

Comment: It's really dumb for a theme author to use a function with the same name as one of WP core functions. As @musical_coder says you'll have to rename this function **and** find all occurrences in the theme and rename too (now comes the complicated part, did it mean the original WP or the theme's function?).